# Rails creating an event for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Rails newbie here, Iam trying to use an association between a user model and event model. A user can create many events. Iam currently using devise for my user model. Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can store the user_id in my events model for the currently logged in user, my current code is as follows:

//////Events controller create method:

```
def create

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @event = @user.events.create(params[:event].permit(:name, :date, :time, :description, :dresscode, :price, :avatar, :avatar2, :avatar3, :avatar4, :user_id))

    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use build method like this

```
@event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
```

Comment: Additionally, since you are using devise, you have a helper method available to you called `current_user` so it could be `current_user.events.build(params[:event])` and don't have to set an instance variable for `user`

Comment: yes right do not use instance variable just use current_user helper in your event controller and build the events..

Answer (score 0):

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :date, :time, :description, :dresscode, :price, :avatar, :avatar2, :avatar3, :avatar4, :user_id))
  end
end
```

Hints:

1. Devise gives you a `current_user` method that returns the user that is signed in.
2. You can `.build` records through the association without actually saving them (as `.create`) would do (for a reference of the methods generated by a `has_many` association see [the Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)).
3. It's customary to extract the `event_params` into a method you can reuse in both the `create` and `update` actions.

Hope this helps!